# WASM react module parse failed: magic header not detected

Tags: reactjs, webassembly

I'm trying to load a simple web assembly module in a react project. The wasm module was compiled with the `MODULARIZE` option.

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Loading_and_running) I've tried incorporating this into my code as follows:

```
fetch('./my-library.wasm')
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(bytes => WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes))
  .then(results => {
    console.log("do something");
  });
```

Where ideally I would like to store the results in the `state` so I can access the module throughout the code (replacing the console log).

Unfortunately this gives me the error

```
Unhandled Rejection (CompileError): wasm validation error: at offset 4: failed to match magic number
```

What am I missing? Compiling without `MODULARIZE` also gives this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried [this](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/using-webassembly-with-react) and [this](https://brightinventions.pl/blog/using-wasm-with-react/) with my module but they didn't work so tried putting the wasm file directly in the public folder and fetching it from there (see also: [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)). It needed some tweaking specific to the use-case of the wasm module (memory settings, etc). My specific case looks like this now

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.loadWasm();
}

loadWasm() {
  const path = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/my-library.wasm';
  const importObject = {
    env: {
      memoryBase: 0,
      tableBase: 0,
      memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({initial: 256, maximum: 1024}),
      table: new WebAssembly.Table({initial: 256, element: 'anyfunc'}),
      __assert_fail: function() {
        // todo
      },
      emscripten_resize_heap: function() {
        // todo
      },
      emscripten_memcpy_big: function() {
        // todo
      },
      setTempRet0: function() {
        // todo
      }
    }
  };
  WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch(path), importObject).then(obj => {
    // do stuff
  });
}
```

**EDIT**

I was getting the magic number error when fetching the wasm from its javascript wrapper (e.g. a.out.js) because of a routing problem with react. At the end of it all I decided it was less of a hassle to just include the javascript as a dependency in the index.html file. This has the advantage of not having to mess with webpack and webpack non messing with the emcc-generated js. Also, not loading the wasm module directly, the emcc-generated js takes care of setting the `importObject`.

Comment: is it possible to send this wasm file, I can help you

Comment: are you not able to describe why the magic number error occurs?

Comment: ok, give me some clue, how do you access the `.wasm` binary ? from your browser script, is it not hosted in your http://localhost with `application/wasm` MIME content type?

Answer (score 3):

To use `.wasm` in any browser as of now, you must host it in any simple server with proper MIME Content-Type, For Example in chrome network tab you must see this kind of response

[image]

Then only the WASM treated as a proper response in your `fetch('./my-library.wasm')` code

You can refer the official documentation [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html#generating-html)

it clearly says

> Unfortunately several browsers (including Chrome, Safari, and Internet Explorer) do not support file:// XHR requests, and can’t load extra files needed by the HTML (like a .wasm file, or packaged file data as mentioned lower down). For these browsers you’ll need to serve the files using a webserver. The easiest way to do this is to use the python SimpleHTTPServer (in the current directory do python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 and then open http://localhost:8080/hello.html).

I can see you are using react, so obviously you do use a local Node.JS server, you need to put the binary along with non-dynamic content which should not be `./`. it should be some other folder where `.css` and `images` are there

**Important Note:** it is mandatory that the response must have `application/wasm`